# Solution on a specific Excel-VBA code is needed

Tags: vba, excel

Below text has to be seen with the picture attached.

```
The part i need to get help with the regarding the VBA code.
```

I would like to be able to write a  New comment under `sheet1` and then press the button "load new comments" ,What should happen when pressing the button:

If any new comments
copy the  information (new comment and Workorder) to sheet2 in first "free row" (Workorder under workorder and New comments to comments)

`Sort Sheet2.Column.Number` with highest number first.

Then Clear `Sheet1.column` "New Comments"

[image: See picture for problemsolving issue]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but everything which can be written in a VBA macro, can also be recorded. I'm advising you to record a macro while you are manually adding your comments, and see in the VBA editor what the recorded macro looks like.

Comment: Im sure aware of that. Still as you can see there are some difficulties that recording not is considering. Such as; there can be empty cells under sheet1.column("new comments"). Sheet2 shall store all comments and npt be erased everytime so the code has to find the first "empty" cell and so on....